# Cannot delete a flow in Nifi registry via http call when using git as storage

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

When using `DELETE` `/buckets/{bucketId}/flows/{flowId}`,

it cannot delete a flow which has version 0.

for example, something like the following flow cannot be deleted via the above http call.

```
{
    "bucketIdentifier": "6a0f624c-3163-496e-bb60-9ca4fe287654",
    "bucketName": "flow_bucket",
    "createdTimestamp": 1550243254914,
    "description": "A Versioned Flow from pyApi",
    "identifier": "d3738331-78b3-4dda-ab6b-a2975db762ff",
    "link": {
        "href": "buckets/6a0f624c-3163-496e-bb60-9ca4fe287654/flows/d3738331-78b3-4dda-ab6b-a2975db762ff",
        "params": {
            "rel": "self"
        }
    },
    "modifiedTimestamp": 1550243254914,
    "name": "test flow by pyApi",
    "permissions": {
        "canDelete": true,
        "canRead": true,
        "canWrite": true
    },
    "type": "Flow",
    "versionCount": 0
}
```

Is there any other way to delete such flow?
This flow is created by 
`nipyapi.versioning.save_flow_ver()` given a different `flow_name`.
Although it fails with `409`, it still creates a flow in Nifi registry.
The storage is git(gitlab specifically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Ben it is likely you are encountering a bug and not intended behavior. In addition to the suggestion to manually edit the H2 metadata database, you could also try adding a flow snapshot version (the versioned flow could be anything), to get version 1 saved for this flow, and then deleting the entire flow. That is:

```
POST /buckets/6a0f624c-3163-496e-bb60-9ca4fe287654/flows/d3738331-78b3-4dda-ab6b-a2975db762ff/versions/
DELETE /buckets/6a0f624c-3163-496e-bb60-9ca4fe287654/flows/d3738331-78b3-4dda-ab6b-a2975db762ff
```

I will open an Apache Jira issue to track fixing this bug.

Comment: the situation happened when versioning a flow which is already versioned with a different `flow_name` using git as storage

Comment: thanks that is useful to reproduce. such a call should probably be treated as a transaction so that it cannot partially succeed. you can watch this Jira to track the fix: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFIREG-228

Comment: cool, I think it's partly resolved, because receiving 409 should not create an entry in the registry? it basically means the process group should not have the other versioned flow with a different versioned flow name, as it already has one versioned flow, or?

Answer (score 2):

Seems unlikely.. Flows in NiFi-Registry start with version 1. If so, it's a bug. You should be able to delete it directly from the filesytem though. The flows are by default held under `{NIFI_INSTALLATION_FOLDER}/flow_storage/{BUCKET_ID}/`. Just remove the directory whose name is this flow id. This should fix it.

EDIT:

forgot to mention that you also need to edit the db file(H2) placed by default in `{NIFI_INSTALLATION_FOLDER}/database`

Comment: I use gitlab as storage. will update it in the description

Comment: @AkiraSendoh should be the same.. Just delete it from your storage(should it be local or git) and remove it from your db as well

Comment: I see. that flow id does not exist in git. next time I will try to find it in the file system